# how can we click the ninth link using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Suppose, i have a list of 10 links available on the web , how can we click the 9th link?

How can we write the code of the same.

```
List li= driver.findElements(By.id("112eed");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple to achieve.
The most common way to iterate lists in selenium is to get the full item list, and get the right item that you need (by the best identifier that you can use)

Pseudo:

```
listOfElements = driver.getElementsBy(By<someSelector>);
if (listOfElements.size() >= 8) {
   link = listOfElements.get(8)
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.